# Floating a div against a position:fixed image where the image width is "auto"

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

The menu and main image are meant to be `"position: fixed"` (the image isn't currently), while the text can scroll next to both.

The image's width is "auto" as it's height must be 100%, however this doesn't give me a fixed point from which to place the text div, so on smaller screens te text overlaps the image.

THe text must be at all points 30px from the image, irrelevant of screen size.

Here's the setup: http://zoesghanakitchen.co.uk/?p=40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly you should put the `div` containing image directly after the `div` of the menu with `position:fixed`. Then adjust your image width and height.